# Dynamic menu using JSON script producing no results

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to produce a menu system that will load buttons that go to a set of videos dynamically, I want to give the menu system button data via a JSON script however I'm having trouble getting the data to display, I have already confirmed my script works with a basic list before modifying it to take JSON data meaning there's no issues with my button prefab.

When I debug.log the json object it produces the file and when I run the game there are no filepath errors which means everything is being read properly. I've also confirmed the panelTransform gameObject is assigned correctly.

The JSON file:

```
{
  "Albania":
  [
    {
      "buttonId": 1,
      "buttonText": "Tirana1"
    },
    {
      "buttonId": 2,
      "buttonText": "Tirana2"
    },
    {
      "buttonId": 3,
      "buttonText": "Tirana3"
    },
    {
      "buttonId": 4,
      "buttonText": "Tirana3"
    }
  ]
}
```

The script attached to my canvas object (contains the panel object):

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;

public class ButtonsMenu1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    //public List<ButtonData> buttonData;
    public GameObject buttonPrefab;
    public Transform panelTransform;
    public string jsonFilePath;

    void Start()
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText(jsonFilePath);
        Debug.Log(json);
        List<ButtonData> buttonData = JsonUtility.FromJson<List<ButtonData>>(json);

        Debug.Log("Panel object: " + panelTransform.name);

        foreach (ButtonData data in buttonData)
        {
            GameObject buttonObj = Instantiate(buttonPrefab, panelTransform); //Instantiates the button within the Transform of the panel
            Button button = buttonObj.GetComponent<Button>(); 
            TMP_Text buttonText = buttonObj.GetComponentInChildren<TMP_Text>();

            button.onClick.AddListener(() => { ButtonClicked(data.buttonId); });
            buttonText.text = data.buttonText;
        }
    }

    void ButtonClicked(int buttonId)
    {
        // Handle button click based on button ID
    }

    public class ButtonData
    {
        public int buttonId;
        public string buttonText;
    }
}
```

Any ideas as to why no buttons display in my game or in the hierarchy?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The json declares an object with a property named "Albania" which is a collection of objects.  The classes also need the Serializable attribute.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Data
{
    public List<ButtonData> Albania;
}
[System.Serializable]
public class ButtonData
{
    public int buttonId;
    public string buttonText;
}

var buttonData = JsonUtility.FromJson<Data>(json);
```